# Querying Office 365 Service Communications API with Python

Tags: python, json, powershell, office365

I am trying to get the name of all Office 365 services by querying the Service Communications API.

I have been able to complete the task using a PowerShell script, but am unable to do the same using Python.

When using Python, I get a 200 response code, but have been unable to parse what is returned. Any help would be much appreciated.

My attempt to convert the PowerShell script to Python is below.

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

username = "username"
password = "password"

# Base Service Communications URI
baseuri = "https://api.admin.microsoftonline.com/shdtenantcommunications.svc"
headers = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
auth = {"username": username, "password": password}
# URI Paths
serviceinfo = "/GetServiceInformation"
register = "/Register"

response = requests.options(baseuri+register, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
print("Registration status code: %s" % response.status_code)
if (response is not None and 200 == response.status_code):
    info = requests.options(baseuri+serviceinfo, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
    print("Info status code: %s" % info.status_code)
    data = json.loads(info.text)
```

The Python script returns an error. Specifically, it returns the following:

```
Registration status code: 200
Info status code: 200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "o365_option.py", line 22, in <module>
    data = json.loads(info.text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your python script. Here is the correct python script to duplicate the results from the powershell script you posted.

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

username = "username"
password = "password"

# Base Service Communications URI
baseuri = "https://api.admin.microsoftonline.com/shdtenantcommunications.svc"
headers = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
auth = {"username": username, "password": password}
# URI Paths
serviceinfo = "/GetServiceInformation"
register = "/Register"

payload = {'userName': username, 'password': password}
myheaders = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data=json.dumps(payload)
response = requests.post(baseuri+register,data=json.dumps(payload),headers=myheaders)
responsedata = json.loads(response.text)
cookie = responsedata.get("RegistrationCookie")

payload1 = {'lastCookie':cookie,'locale':"en-US"} 
response = requests.post(baseuri+serviceinfo,data=json.dumps(payload1),headers=myheaders)
responsedata = json.loads(response.text)
for myobject in responsedata:
   print myobject.get("ServiceName")
```

This is the response you will get:

```
"Exchange Online"
"Office Subscription"
"Identity Service"
"Office 365 Portal"
"Skype for Business"
"SharePoint Online"
"Rights Management Service"
"Yammer Enterprise"
"OneDrive for Business"
"Mobile Device Management"
```

Additionally, please note that there is a new version of the Office 365 Service Communications API in public preview which is available here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn707385.aspx

It has a few new methods that might be interesting to you, and is a bit easier to develop against. The new API follows the OAuth 2.0 flow that the other Microsoft APIs are using. If you are using multiple Microsoft APIs, than you will be familiar with the flow already.

Let me know if this answers your question or if have any additional questions.

Comment: Hi Frank. A followup question I have. Does the link I've included a complete list of all Office 365 services that a user can subscribe to? I see services returned by the API request (ex. Rights Management Service), that I don't see in the TechNet doc below.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819284%28v=technet.10%29

Comment: Furthermore, I've used the new public preview Service Communications API to retrieve the subscribed services. That API, however, does not return the same output as the old Service Communications API. Is this because it is still in public preview and not yet fully implemented?

For example, the old API request returns Yammer, but the new API does not.

Comment: Hi, the TechNet doc you linked does not have the complete list of services you can obtain service communications for. Furthermore, the list of services is constantly changing, so it is best not to refer to a static list. Try not to hard code a list of services, instead handle the services dynamically so that adding or deleting services has no impact on your system.

Comment: The v1 and v2 API have slightly different responses. However, the services returned by both APIs should be the same. If you can repro the example you gave, and add a screenshot, we will take a look at what is causing the difference.

Comment: I found my problem. I was comparing the results of 2 different accounts. Dumb mistake. Sorry. However, while we're on the subject, is there a way to programatically retrieve the authentication code? Rather than manually entering the URL and manually granting access, I would like the user to be able to enter just their redirect url, username, password, and client id to get the authorization code.

Comment: You should not ask the user for their username and password. That is one of the key benefits of OAuth. Users should be able to grant your application permission to their tenants data without worrying that your application will misuse their credentials. However, user intervention is only needed to get the authorization code, so it is a one time process. Your app can use access tokens and refresh tokens to continue to access the tenants data.

Comment: Hi Frank. Does the Service Communications API use the Identity service for authentication? When running the script above, I get a 401 response code when trying to retrieve the registration token. I checked in my Office 365 portal and see that the Identity Service is currently under extended recovery. Prior to today, the script was working and no other changes have been made. I've tried other admin accounts also to no avail. Could the service health of the Identity service be causing this Unauthorized error?

Comment: Yes, we had a short outage. This should be resolved now. Please let us know if you continue to experience issues.

Comment: Hi Frank, Is there a complete list of services that are offered by Office 365? The documentation I've found doesn't seem to be a complete list. For example, we're seeing services such as "Social Engagement" and "Microsoft Dynamics Marketing", which aren't mentioned in the documents we're using as reference.

Comment: The list of services change quite often as new services are being added and old ones removed almost every week. Please see my previous comment on this.